# DwmRegisterThumbnail unable to capture browser when its on background

Tags: google-chrome, winapi, browser, microsoft-edge, dwm

Im using the winapi [DwmRegisterThumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail) to capture the browser thumbnail to my GUI, however when i move the browser to background it stop rendering the thumbnail, my thought its a browser setting to reduce use of resources or something like?

If i move the mouse over the browser at the taskbar, it creates the thumbnail and start capturing it, however as soon the thumbnail is closed it stops capturing.

It only happens on `browsers` (tested chrome, edge and opera), i also have tested many other applications and i was able to capture the thumbnail correctly even when these windows was on background.

Does someone know something about it?

Comment: All of the named browsers are Chromium-based. What you noticed is an energy safety feature called [occlusion tracking](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_native_window_occlusion_tracking.md).  _"If a window is occluded, Chromium treats foreground tabs as if they were background tabs; rendering stops, and js is throttled."_

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by changing the flag:

```
chrome://flags/#calculate-native-win-occlusion
```

From "default" to "disabled".

source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/l1eec1/psa_disable_window_occlusion_calculation_on/

Thank you `zett42` for pointing it!